# C++ Map can't insert with pair

Tags: c++, dictionary, visual-studio-2008, insert

Why can't I insert as shown below?

```
#include <map>

struct something {

} some_object;

typedef std::map<std::string, something*> list;
typedef std::pair<std::string, something*> pair;

int main()
{
    list l;
    pair p("abc", &some_object); // working fine!!!
    l.insert(p); // 17 errors

    return 0;
}
```

Visual studio gives me many errors and I don't understand anything of them. The first one is:

```
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const std::string'
```

I can post more but I don't want to spam here. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You've hit upon one of my pet hates by using "cant" rather than "can't".  "cant" is a word in its own right and has a completely different meaning to cannot:  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: wow ... so fast, and so stupid mistake.. i didnt realize this mistake.. but why 17 errors for this simple thing ? :S

Comment: I'm more surprised that it let the several other references to std::string compile before complaining about that one...

Comment: Template errors cascade. If it cannot do operator< on a string, then it cannot do X on Y, then Y on Z, etc...

Comment: Hm, gcc borks on line 7 with: "string is not a member of std". A lot clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I would change this line:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, something*> pair;
```

You are relaying on an implementation detail. Are you sure this wil always be true for all future version of the library? Tightly coupling your code like that is a bad idea.

Try this:

```
typedef list::value_type pair;
```

PS. 'list' would not be my first choice for the name of a type I put in the global namespace. Either put it in your own namespace or call it 'MyList'.